# General questions about qooxdoo

Tags: qooxdoo

thank you for developing qooxdoo. It's a great Javascript library, I used it years ago and it was very impressive.

Developers who are looking for a lib to create their project around probably have the same questions, I could not find safe answers for the following questions:

Q: Is qooxdoo active and future proof? Are there developers dedicated with long term plans for qooxdoo?

Q: Can qooxdoo be integrated in an IDE for client development (code completion)?

I really would like to use qx for another project and will give back in this process.

Regards,

Mike

Answer (score 3):

> Is qooxdoo active and future proof?

Yes, very much so - the "core team" of developers (of which I'm one) develop it and develop with it on a daily basis, and there is a growing number of people who develop Qooxdoo based applications.

We are actively preparing to release v6.0 in the next month or so, and while this will be the first major release for several years, the `master` branch at https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo is really very stable and we all use it in production.  There's no coding waiting for 6.0, it's just about finalising the website and some of the documentation.

There are lots of new features, including a new compiler for ES6, a command line tool, and improvements to the library itself.

> Are there developers dedicated with long term plans for qooxdoo?

Yes, we're already planning v7.0.

> Can qooxdoo be integrated in an IDE for client development (code completion)?

There is a typescript definitions file which is output, and that gives code completion in Visual Studio (and presumably other IDEs as well).  The new compiler produces this on the fly, so you have code completion on your own code as well as the Qooxdoo framework.

We talk on Gitter, and the public chat is at https://gitter.im/qooxdoo/qooxdoo

Answer (score 2):

> Can qooxdoo be integrated in an IDE for client development (code completion)?

We are assembling a list of IDEs with code completion here:
http://www.qooxdoo.org/docs/#/development/development_tools

The JetBrain IDEs (i.e. PHPStorm and WebStorm) have excellent Qooxdoo support with code analysis - it even understands the qooxdoo classes and properties

Comment: Add JetBrains PyCharm to this list.